# Find alternative for Debian 5 to work with big files

Tags: debian, find, x86

I have a problem using find

```
find ./  -mtime +7

Value too large for defined data type
```

because of 2 Gb file (backup) on x32 VDS and it is not possible to reinstall OS.

I need to remove old files but this error makes not possible to use find + xarg + rm.

Reinstallation of GNU coreutils did not help. Also file have name with creation date, for example "2012_04_03.tar", may be this can be used for removing old files.

Answer (score 1):

Seems, that this [explanation](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/faq/#Value-too-large-for-defined-data-type) may help you.

Short description:
This error means that your version of the utilities were not compiled with large file support enabled. You can try to recompile it with large file support and if you're lucky everything will be fine =)

Comment: Can you describe exact way of doing this? Because your link says `This is typically done by defining -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 or some such. It is system dependent` and nothing concrete